# Control SmartScreen Anti-Malware Filter

Tags: windows-8

What are the ways to disable the `SmartScreen Anti-Malware Filter` for IE/Chrome/Firefox on Windows 8?

One way is to update the "Windows Defender".

I want to know a simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

- Head to the classic Control Panel.
- Select "System and Security".
- Select "Action Center".
- Expand the list and scroll down to "Windows SmartScreen".
- Select "Change settings" link.
- Select "Turn off Windows SmartScreen".
- Hit OK.

[image]

More info [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/75356/how-to-turn-off-or-disable-the-smartscreen-filter-in-windows-8/)